# Anchoring trick isn't working in Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

This code has different result in Firefox and Chrome

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:50%; height:50px; position:relative;">
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:20px;" />
</div>
```

[image]

How to make the text box anchored 0px to the left and 20px to the right side of the div?

NOTE: div's width must fluid 50%.

Thank you :)

Comment: Does the input field need to fit the container or just be anchored to 20px from the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:50%; height:50px; position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:20px;">
        <input type="text" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`<input>` behaves badly in some browsers, wrap it in a div

Comment: What in the world are you doing with that extra div!? Remove it now before I shoot you.

Comment: `<input>` doesn't behave the same as a regular block element with both `left:` and `right:` set at the same time in FF, but it does understand `width: 100%`. If you have a better solution, let's see it :)

Comment: @Litso Do you have a solution to remove extra div? It will be great :)

Comment: Sorry, no. Tested it and have to agree with Krio, despite the extra div.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of `left:0;`

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:50%; height:50px; position:relative;">
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute; right:20px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: im sorry, i want it anchored 0px to the left as well

Answer (score 0):

"How to make the text box anchored 20px to the right side of the div?" Either I don't get what you mean by this, or the example works perfectly fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/GmMCQ/

Answer (score 0):

How about using box-sizing on the outer `<div>`? This way you can avoid adding an extra one:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:50%; height:50px; position:relative; padding-right:20px; box-sizing:border-box;">
    <input type="text" style="width:100%;" />
</div>
```

Of course, this would only apply if you didn't mind adding the padding to the outer `<div>`...

Tested in FF 4.0 & Chrome 10.0